# What do the `s around table/field names in SQL mean?

Tags: sql, mysql, syntax

Here's an SQL statement that phpMyAdmin generated for me:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE 1
```

You can see that `table_name` is surrounded by ` characters.

Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's used to enclose [identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) in MySQL.

It lets them have characters that would be ambiguous or otherwise invalid in normal SQL, such as a space:

```
`foo bar` - is a valid MySQL identifier

foo bar - is not, since foo is the identifier, and bar is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 3):

Its used as to escape/enclose characters, in case of a space or some other illegal character in the table or field name.

From the docs:

> If an identifier contains
>   special characters or is a reserved
>   word, you must quote it whenever you
>   refer to it. The set of alphanumeric
>   characters from the current character
>   set, “_”, and “$” are not special.
>   Reserved words are listed at Section
>   8.3, “Reserved Words”.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: Would it be a bad idea if for let's say an ORM to use these for any table name?

Comment: @emanuil the ORM uses it by default around all tables/fields to be safe. i find it rather annoying.

Comment: Why would you find it annoying?